# Java generics, convert nested list to array

Tags: java, array, generics

I have to interface to some old code using nested arrays, so I have to convert my nested Lists to nested arrays. Any idea, suggestions, improvements are warmly welcomed.

```
public static <E> int getNestedListMaxSize(List<List<E>> list){
    int result = 0;
    if (list != null && list.size() > 0){
        for (List<E> innerList : list){
            result = Math.max(result, innerList == null ? 0 : innerList.size());
        }
    }
    return result;
}

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public static <E> Class getNestedListClass(List<List<E>> list){
    Class result = null;
    if (list != null && list.size() > 0){
        for (List<E> innerList : list){
            if (innerList != null && innerList.size() > 0){
                result = innerList.get(0).getClass();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
public static <E> E[][] convertNestedList(List<List<E>> list){
    E[][] result = null;
    Class clazz = getNestedListClass(list);
    if (clazz != null){
        result = (E[][]) Array.newInstance(clazz, list.size(), getNestedListMaxSize(list));

        for(int i=0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            E[] element = null;
            if (list.get(i) != null){
                E[] dummy = (E[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, list.get(i).size());
                element = list.get(i).toArray(dummy);
            }
            result[i] = element;
        }           
    }
    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    list.add(new ArrayList<String>());
    list.get(list.size()-1).add("0.0");
    list.get(list.size()-1).add("0.1");
    list.get(list.size()-1).add("0.2");
    list.add(new ArrayList<String>());
    list.get(list.size()-1).add("1.0");
    list.get(list.size()-1).add("1.1");
    list.get(list.size()-1).add("1.2");
    list.get(list.size()-1).add("1.3");
    list.add(new ArrayList<String>());
    list.get(list.size()-1).add("2.0");
    list.get(list.size()-1).add("2.1");

    String [][] array = convertNestedList(list);

    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use [guard clauses](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/01/flattening-arrow-code.html) to check whether the list parameter is `null` or not. Furthermore, the `list.size() > 0` check looks unnecessary in the first two methods, the result will be same if you omit it.

Anyway, are you sure that `null` is an acceptable parameter here? Wouldn't it better to throw an exception in this case?

```
public static <E> int getNestedListMaxSize(final List<List<E>> list) {
    if (list == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    int result = 0;
    for (final List<E> innerList: list) {
        if (innerList == null) {
            continue;
        }
        result = Math.max(result, innerList.size());
    }
    return result;
}
```

In the `getNestedListClass` I'd use guard clauses too and a `return` instead of the `break`.

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public static <E> Class getNestedListClass(final List<List<E>> list) {
    if (list == null) {
        return null;
    }

    for (final List<E> innerList: list) {
        if (innerList == null || innerList.isEmpty()) {
            continue;
        }
        return innerList.get(0).getClass();
    }
    return null;
}
```

I think the `return` makes the code much easier to read and follow.

In the `convertNestedList` method

1. the `dummy` variable should have a meaningful name, for example `innerListArray`,
2. the default value of `result[i]` is `null`, so you don't have to set it to `null` explicitly if the inner list is `null`,
3. `list.get(i)` is called three times. It could have a local variable.

```
public static <E> E[][] convertNestedList(final List<List<E>> list) {
    final Class<?> clazz = getNestedListClass(list);
    if (clazz == null) {
        return null;
    }
    final E[][] result = (E[][]) Array.newInstance(clazz, list.size(), 
        getNestedListMaxSize(list));

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        final List<E> innerList = list.get(i);
        if (innerList == null) {
            continue;
        }
        final E[] innerListArray = (E[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, innerList.size());
        result[i] = innerList.toArray(innerListArray);
    }
    return result;
}
```

The main method should be a unit test method with proper assert calls:

```
@Test
public void testConvertNestedList() {
    final List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    list.add(new ArrayList<String>());
    list.get(list.size() - 1).add("0.0");
    list.get(list.size() - 1).add("0.1");
    list.get(list.size() - 1).add("0.2");
    list.add(new ArrayList<String>());
    list.get(list.size() - 1).add("1.0");
    list.get(list.size() - 1).add("1.1");
    list.get(list.size() - 1).add("1.2");
    list.get(list.size() - 1).add("1.3");
    list.add(new ArrayList<String>());
    list.get(list.size() - 1).add("2.0");
    list.get(list.size() - 1).add("2.1");

    final String[][] array = ListConvert.convertNestedList(list);

    // @formatter:off
    final String[][] expected = new String[][] { 
            { "0.0", "0.1", "0.2" }, 
            { "1.0", "1.1", "1.2", "1.3" },
            { "2.0", "2.1" } };
    // @formatter:on
    assertArrayEquals(expected, array);
}
```

It helps detecting regressions.

Comment: I was worried I made some conceptual error, like there was a much simpler way to achieve my goal. Nevertheless, these are all valid and good remarks, so thanks @palacsint.

Comment: An idea: have you searched for already existed libraries which does this?

Comment: Well, I searched on Google/StackOverflow and nothing surfaced. I also thought to myself that such feature should be already implemented in some existing library. I have checked Apache Commons and Guava but I did not find it.